# How to validate an AMP page with custom JavaScript and Browse on mobile and desktop

Tags: amp-html

According to latest AMP we can use custom JavaScript. Unfortunately I could see an amp page with custom JavaScript on my mobile phone working. Or am I missing a browser that is able to browse amp pages?

How could I test and validate, preferably on desktop?

Answer (score 0):

To use custom JavaScript in AMP pages, you need the [amp-script component](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-script/) which is under "Origin Trial" so it can't be used in production.

To test and validate custom JS, you need to sign up for the [Origin Trial](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/experimental/?format=websites#origin-trials) 
and make sure your JS is AMP compatible  - for example, you can only fire JS on user interaction, not on page load, etc.

If you need custom JavaScript for pages, either include them via  `amp-iframe` or code a non AMP page.

Comment: iFrame would not work for my purpose, so I go for amp-script. At the moment is fine not to use it in production. I guess you are an insider of AMP, because amp.dev page https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/develop/custom-javascript does not make it clear, that Origin Trail is necessary.
Is there another way, a simple Browser? I mean somehow AMP developers are testing all the new things as well, so how you test on localhost without an internet connection? Without being tracked?

Comment: Heh, I guess the devs in AMP HQ have a way of testing stuff in secret, but for the rest of us we need internet connection for AMP to work . Here is a tutorial on how to enable experimental mode https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/experimental/ to rest features in experimental mode.